# DbGeometry curves

Tags: c#, entity-framework

While I appreciate that `SQL spatial support` in EF is new, I am missing support for curves.

Eg, my COMPOUNDCURVE is made up of `CircularString` and line segments, but all I can get is a list of points (with no context as to which segment they are in), as the elements are just itself (whole compound curve).

So, at the moment, my approach is to convert the `DbGeometry` to `SqlGeometry` using the well-known-text, and then get the STCurveN segments, etc.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: i have the same question ?

Comment: also with STCurveN  I always get null